# End of file on pipe magic during open

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, wireshark, popen

I have a c++ application in which I am starting another process(wireshark) something like following.

```
   if (fp == NULL){
    fp = popen(processpath, "r"); //processpath is the process I want to start
    if (!fp){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Cannot start process");        
    }
    fprintf(fp, d_msg);//d_msg is the input I want to provide to process 
} else if(fp != NULL){
    fprintf(fp, d_msg);
}
```

The problem is when I execute my c++ application, it does start the wireshark but with error `End of File on pipe magic during open`

what should I do to avoid that?

Also I tried using mkfifo to create a named pipe and execute it. I used something like this:

```
   if (fp == NULL){
    system("mkfifo /tmp/mine.pcap");
    fp = popen("wireshark -k -i /tmp/mine.pcap", "r");
    if (!fp){
        dout << "Cannot start wireshark"<<std::endl;
        throw std::invalid_argument("Cannot start wireshark");      
    }
    input = fopen("/tmp/mine.pcap", "wb");
    fprintf(input , d_msg);
    fclose(input);
} else if(fp != NULL){
    input = fopen("/tmp/mine.pcap", "wb");
    fprintf(input , d_msg);
    fclose(input);
}
```

But that too didn't work. With this I get following error:

`The file "/tmp/wireshark_mine.pcap_20130730012654_ndbFzk" is a capture for a network type that Wireshark doesn't support`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You've seen that you opened the pipe with `"r"`, i.e. for reading instead of writing?

Comment: You open the pipe for reading and fprintf something to it.

Comment: "You open the pipe for reading and fprintf something to it."  Not if you're piping to a named pipe on which Wireshark is capturing, you don't, as you have to write a [pcap file](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html) or a [pcap-ng file](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) to Wireshark, and *neither* of those are text files.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. Doesnt `"r"` makes one end of pipe readable and another end writable? May be I understood it wrong. 
@GuyHarris: Actually I have pcap headers in my c++ application which I wish to pass to wireshark directly. So should I create a pcap file(with the header etc) and then do the mkfifp and use it to write the packets?

Comment: "Doesnt "r" makes one end of pipe readable and another end writable?"  Yes, but the end you get from `popen()` will only be readable, not writable.  If you open with "w", you get the writable end.

Comment: My mistake. Somehow I understood it wrong way. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is when I execute my c++ application, it does start the wireshark but with error `End of File on pipe magic during open`
>
> what should I do to avoid that?

You should write a [pcap file](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html) or a [pcap-ng file](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) to the pipe, rather than fprintfing something.

Both of those file formats are *binary*.  If you're constructing your own packets, you will have to construct and write to the pipe a valid pcap file header or several valid pcap-ng blocks (Section Header Block and at least one Interface Description Block) before you can write any packets, and then, for each packet, you will have to write a per-packet pcap header or the beginning *and* end of a pcap-ng Enhanced Packet Block before (and, for an Enhanced Block, after) the raw packet data.  If you're just sending an existing file to Wireshark, you will need to read raw bytes from the file and send those raw bytes down the pipe.

Comment: Clear Enough. I am constructing valid pcap-headers and pcap-file-header both with all the [details](http://pastie.org/8193003). and I am providing each of them. Then also I am having the same issue. May be I will check it again and ask again here, is that fine?

Comment: If I write the pcap file header and pcap per packet headers using the named pipe(the second method mentioned in question) that should work, right?

Comment: Radiotap header?  Then `d_link` must be 127; if it's not 127, that won't work.  Also, make sure all the fields in the structures have the appropriate size; do not, for example, use `long` or `unsigned long` for sizes, as those might be 64-bit on 64-bit systems.

Comment: [Radiotap header](http://www.radiotap.org/) is just an additional way to provide more information.  Yes `d_link'` is [127](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/pcap-linktype/). But I am still not getting it correct. I got the point about `w` with `popen` but still it just keeps waiting for the capture. If interested please have a look over the [code](http://pastie.org/pastes/8196181/text). The pipe is towards the end.

Comment: `fp = popen("wireshark -k -i -", "r");` should be `fp = popen("wireshark -k -i -", "w");`, as you're trying to write to Wireshark, not read *from* Wireshark (if you want to read decrypted packets from a pipe, use TShark, not Wireshark).

Comment: `d_msg` shouldn't be a `char *`, as what you write on the pipe to Wireshark are ***NOT*** text characters, they're binary bytes.  It should be a `uint8_t`, if those are available in the version of C++ you're using.  You should write it with `fwrite()`, ***NOT*** `fprintf()`, as it's ***NOT*** a format string or other form of text.

Comment: Hi @GuyHarris, thanks a lot for your inputs. I tried with fwrite and I dont have any error as previous. Although I still get error `Frame 5 too long`. Any idea what is that about?

Comment: What you got was probably `Frame 5 too long (NNN bytes)`, for some value of "NNN".  "NNN" is what dumpcap read as the "captured length" of the packet in the per-packet header (`hdr->incl_len`), and it must be <= 65535.  If it's a bit larger, you need to write smaller packets; if it's a *lot* larger, it might be that you're writing the packet header wrong.